# What did computers use for output before monitors?

Tags: display, history

How did the early industrial computers, such as [UNIVAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univac), [ENIAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eniac), [MARK I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Mark_I), etc display output before monitors existed?

Did the first personal computers, like the [Altair 8800](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800) or the [Simon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28computer%29) use monitors, or did they use some alternate output as well?

Comment: Punch cards, punch tape, teletypes, .... the list goes on. The PC didn't take off until there were cheap monitors.

Comment: @ChrisF: I'd debate that the PC didn't take off until Lotus 123 showed up.

Comment: Unix systems still refer to text-mode terminals as "tty", teletype. Computers used to use teletypes.

Comment: Punched cards, line printers, teletypes, paper tape, in 1962, when I first worked on them. There were some pretty amazing machines. like the line printer could print on multi-layer paper with carbon paper in between. Then it would be run through a burster-decollater to separate the copies.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus

Comment: "We've all got our switches, lights, and knobs to deal with, Striker. I mean, down here there are literally hundreds and thousands of blinking, beeping, and flashing lights, blinking, beeping and flashing - they're flashing and they're beeping." [-Airplane II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083530/)

Comment: No one remembers storage tubes?

Comment: @Random - Why was this closed?

Comment: What's the problem you need fixing here? Or is this just a history lesson?

Comment: @random - This is a question related to computer hardware and there is a canonical answer. The community seems to think it should be opened, judging by the number of up votes and reopen votes. It doesn't have to be a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: @random why was this closed? I think it fits into the [tag:faq] of this sight.

Comment: The answers are all over the place as to what constitutes the meaning of the first computer, ill-defined in the question, and half of them say to just look up Wikipedia, this is either not a real question or not constructive @nea

Comment: To avoid extended discussion here, I've [posted on meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3778/is-this-question-really-off-topic-not-constructive).

Comment: I have an old game programming book.  All the programs included a small blurb about their history, some of which reference printing everthing on paper...

Comment: Folks that had the money would buy a used Teletype for their Altairs.  I fixed up old Teletypes for several people back in that era.  There were also "glass teletypes" -- crude text-only video terminals.  When Centronics came out with their (relatively) inexpensive dot matrix printer it signaled a sea change in small computer peripherals.

Comment: Where's the research behind this question?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first computers used punch cards or lights. Wikipedia says for [ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC):

> an IBM card punch was used for output

The German Wikipedia-article about [Zuse's Z3](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuse_Z3) (the first apparatus that can be called computer) says:

> einer Tastatur mit Lampenfeld für Ein- und Ausgabe von Zahlen und manuelle Steuerung von Berechnungen

That means: it had a keyboard with lights for input and output (programs were read from punch cards, as [NobbZ said](https://superuser.com/a/363409)).

As computers got more common, they used often the already existent [teletypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter), that means output was made through printing text on paper. Until today, Unix-Terminal emulate to some degree teletypes.

**EDIT:** You asked specifically about PCs. First PCs came up in the 50s and had different methods for output. The [IBM 610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_610) used a keyboard for input and an electric typewriter for output. Also, some other early PCs used printers, i.e. [Olivetti Programma 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programma_101). The [Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28computer%29) or the [Kenbak-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenbak-1) used lamps for output.

Monitors seem to come up 20 years later, in the 70s. One early model with monitor is the [Datapoint 2200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datapoint_2200) from 1970. And naturally, the milestone [Xerox Alto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Alto).

More infos about history of PCs at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_personal_computers#The_beginnings_of_the_personal_computer_industry) (as usual).

Comment: The [Altair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800) used front panel toggle switches (although you could hook up a teletype to its RS-232 interface), so I'm not sure how far you want to go back. Maybe the Altair is considered a "hobbyist" computer, rather than a "personal" computer?

Comment: Simon is older than the IBM 610 and is arguably the first *personal computer*

Comment: Many of the early PCs, such as the Apple I, hooked up to a standard television for output.

Comment: Relevant Willy Wonka video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sFYSW6QHCQ

Comment: @rlemon: Wikipedia states the IBM would be first, but the dates itself are strange. I reword that.

Comment: @Antwortgenossenschaft when I said "arguably the first personal computer" I meant due to the fact that the IBM 610 was larger than my desk.

Comment: @rlemon: In any way, the beginnings always unclear so it is better not to say which one is the first PC.

Comment: I remember reading (ca 1970, in a computer journal) about a Russian computer of the same era.  The government did not trust people to have keypunches or printers, so all input/output was switches and lights, even though this was (based on their reports) a "big" machine.

Answer (score 21):

You may want to check out [the Computer History museum's timeline](http://www.computerhistory.org/timeline/) or http://www.thocp.net/index.html

It's been a while since I spent much time there but it is very interesting and may be helpful.  It will probably give you some computer names that you could then research to find out how people interacted with them.

Comment: Really nice resource. Nice answer.

Comment: Yeah, if you go to the second link, under the hardware section and look at the "teletype" you realise how far back the keyboard goes. This even makes me appreciate the mono video terminals I started on in '80.

Answer (score 16):

Before monitors, computers used [Punch Cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC), [Paper Tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Mark_I), [Banks of Lights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28computer%29), [Fan Fold Paper](https://superuser.com/questions/363403/what-did-computers-use-for-output-before-monitors/363643#363643), and [Bells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) for output.

When I was going to school, we submitted our programs to the sysadmin (input) on [punch cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt85P.png) and the output was printed on [fanfold paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH8I7.jpg).

To answer your specific questions:

- [MARK I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Mark_I) (1944): Used a 24 channel punched paper tape for [input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B2lr.jpg).  Or for alternate manual data entry, 60 sets of 24 switches could be used.
- [ENIAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) (1946): Used a card reader for input, and a card punch for output.
- [Simon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28computer%29) (1950): Used a five hole tape for input and five lights for output.
- [UNIVAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_I) (1951) Used a keyboard for input and [register lights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdtUD.jpg) for output.
- [Xerox Alto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Alto) (1973): Used mouse and keyboard for input and a *Monitor* for output.
- [MITS Altair 8800](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800) (1975): Used [an ASCII keyboard for input and a '32 character alphanumeric display terminal' for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qijW5.jpg).

To illustrate an alternate input / output method in use near the dawn of the PC:

- [Pong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong) (1975): Used two knobs for input and a TV for output.

Some other early computers:

- [Zuse Z1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_(computer)) (1938)
- [Zuse Z2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_(computer)) (1939)
- [Zuse Z3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_(computer)) (1941): Used punched 35 mm film stock.
- [Atanasoff–Berry Computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atanasoff%E2%80%93Berry_Computer) (1942)
- [Colossus Mark 1 & 2](http://www.bletchleypark.org.uk/colosusfilm.rhtm) (1944): Used patch cables and switches and paper tape for input and banks of lights for output.
- [Zuse Z4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z4_(computer)) (1945): Used punched 35 mm film stock.
- [Manchester Small-Scale Experimental Machine (Baby)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Small-Scale_Experimental_Machine) (1948)
- [Modified ENIAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) (1948)
- [EDSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Delay_Storage_Automatic_Calculator) (1949)
- [CSIRAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSIRAC) (1949)

And even before all that:

- [Mechanical Calculator (Pascal)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_calculator) (1642)
- Jacquard Loom (1801)
- Scheutzian Calculation Engine (based on the design of the [Difference Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine)) (1843)
- [Arithmometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmometer) (1851)
- [Difference Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) (1859): As @artistoex pointed out, used a bell and a typewriter.

And even before that, as @WernerCD and @artistoex pointed out, calculation assistance has been going on for quite a while:

- [Tally Sticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_stick) (33,000 BC)
- [Counting Pebbles](http://www.sheep101.info/history.html) (Used to keep track of sheep, ~8000 BC)
- [Egyptian Abacus](http://www.computermuseum.li/Testpage/99HISTORYCD-Evolution-of-Counting.HTM) (3,000 BC)
- [Abacus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus) ([2400 BC](http://history-computer.com/CalculatingTools/abacus.html))
- [Antikythera Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism) (100 BC)
- [Counting Rods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_rods) (~100 AD)
- [Planisphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planisphere) (1000 AD)

Comment: Teletype. Why /dev is populated with all those tty devices...

Comment: Yes indeed, I remember the [ASR-33 Teletype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASR-33_Teletype) with its smooth rolls of paper.  The first game I played was [Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure) on a Teletype.

Comment: 35,000 BC: [Tally Sticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_stick)

Comment: @artistoex Well done!  I'll add that in, thank you.

Comment: @Sean I quoted the wiki article incorrectly--it reads 35,000 yrs _ago_ rather than 35,000 BC. I'm sorry.

Comment: @artistoex Thanks for the date fix.  Changed to 33,000 BC

Comment: IBM 2250 Vector graphics in the 1960s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bI164G26dg

Answer (score 8):

There have been many I/O devices in the history of computing, from simple light emitting devices such as incandescent light bulbs (and later LEDs) to punch cards to mechanically operated alpha-numerical displays.  Pretty much any way you can think of interacting with *anything* has probably been used to interact with computers, such as bells, whistles and other such things.

Arrays of lights were probably the simplest form of monitor as they could be used in a similar way to the pixels you see on monitors these days.

Monitors are only one of the many ways that have been devised to interact with computers and it stuck because it is the most intuitive and technologically realistic method of dealing with information.

Answer (score 5):

Since first Computer is known to be the [Zuse Z1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuse_Z1) (at least the first binary computer), I looked at it in wikipedia. But all I could find there was that the input was with punched tape. So I would guess, that the output comes on puched tapes too.

Probably you could find it interesting to go through that wikipedia-pages?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how early you mean, but printers are also output units. You punched in the program, and when it was done it printed the result.

Comment: +1:If you talk to someone who understand printer drivers, they'll tell you  old printer drivers **literally** just redirected the screen output but through a different port.

Comment: @surfasb that's a PC-centric view. UNIX systems, on the other hand, used teletypewriters (a type of printer), and a modern system simulates one (well, more or less - what it actually simulates is a VT100, which is a type of keyboard-and-monitor device that replaced teletypes) on the screen.

Comment: @Random832: That is essentially what I was eluding to, but ya.

Comment: @Random832 - I used the term "printer" here rather liberally; telewriters included (amongst some other things as well).

Comment: My issue was with surfasb's claim that computers naturally had screen output and "printer drivers" are redirecting that output to the printer. (I suspect this is an incorrect oversimplification even for PCs, but that's another issue)

Comment: @Random832 - Oh, no. I didn't mean that. I ment to say that printers are output devices, just like screens (of any kind), and that at some time they were used instead of ... Feel free to edit the answer if you think of how it can be better phrased.

Comment: We had an old teletype machine back where I went to college.  Normally you used a VT100 terminal, but when you needed a printout, you just did your whole session from the teletype.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Besides all the other output devices mentioned in otehr answers, **TV sets** were used for output by many computers in the 80s, like Spectrum, Commodore 64, etc.

Comment: +1, but a TV is really just a monitor. In ye olden days, a low quality monitor with an RF tuner, but the changes in the technology of monitors have been much more significant than the difference between a monitor and a TV at any particular point in time. These days, the difference between a monitor and a TV is probably even less - odds are already significant and increasing that both will recieve an identical signal via HDMI, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

The [Difference Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) used brass digits, a bell and a typewriter.

Answer (score 0):

The first "PC" related to what is commonly known as a PC today, the IBM 5150, used a monitor.  You could obtain the system with a high-resolution text mode-only MDA card, or a lower-resolution text and/or color graphics CGA card.  Around this time (1981) many home computers were designed to be connected to a television, and the CGA card could indeed be connected to a television.

The late 60's/early 70's saw the introduction of video terminals.  These combined a keyboard, CRT display, and character generating hardware and were connected to a minicomputer or mainframe by way of some form of an RS-232 port.  So for a while the "monitor" or terminal was considered part of separate self-contained peripheral.

The Altair 8800 had LEDs which you could use to show output if you did not connect a serial terminal to it.

Before the introduction of video terminals you had teletypes.  Before then you had punch cards.

Comment: That's not the first PC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_personal_computers#The_beginnings_of_the_personal_computer_industry

Comment: PC was an abbreviation for "Personal Computer" before the IBM PC was thought of. PC World magazine (the UK one) even started up before the first IBM PC was released, and covered the personal computers of that time such as the Commodore PET and Apple Lisa. IBM effectively stole a generic term, but since it became generic again (though with a different meaning) afterwards... Anyway, even if the IBM 5150 had been the first PC, it still wasn't the first computer.

Comment: @Steve314: edits made

Comment: Yeah, IBM's previous attempt was called the [5100 "Portable Computer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_5100) (at 55 pounds).  It incorporated into the single case a keyboard, a 5" B&W display (16x6), and a DC300 tape drive (writing a non-standard format).

Comment: But probably the first "PC" should be considered to be the [HP 9100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewlett-Packard_9100A), though some would give this honor to the [Olivetti Programma 101](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programma_101).

Comment: (Oops -- make that display 16x64.)